# Can you use the MongoDB $and operator with different keys?

Tags: mongodb

It seems like these two queries should be identical but the results aren't the same.  Why doesn't the 2nd findOne query with a $and operator do the same thing as the first?

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
connecting to: test
> db.test.drop()
true
> db.test.insert({ x: 1, y: 2 })
> db.test.findOne({ x: 1, y: 2 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f0885cd61d25fd4a5813ae2"), "x" : 1, "y" : 2 }
> db.test.findOne({ $and: [{ x: 1 }, { y: 2 }] })
null
```

I'm using MongoDB 2.0.2 installed via Homebrew on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: Can't reproduce. On my system it works correctly. What version are you using?

Comment: No problem with mongo version 2.0.0

Comment: Maybe it's something with 2.0.2, I filed a bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4646

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, this was caused because I originally installed mongodb 1.8.2 via homebrew, and then I upgraded it to 2.0.2, but I didn't copy the new plist file into place, so launchctl was still starting the 1.8.2.  You can see this because when you connect via the shell:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
```

that's saying you are using version 2.0.2 of the client.  But if you run this:

```
>  db.serverStatus()
```

Somewhere in the output you will see this:

```
"version" : "2.0.2"
```

Which is which version the server is running.  It said 1.8.2 before and now it says 2.0.2.